# Reading space separated integers Java

Tags: java

The user will read an input line with space separated integers, the length of this line is not given,
I want to store this line into 2d array(matrix), which has 4 columns and i rows where `i=length_of_line/4`, in other words I want to make a row from each four elements in the line i.e dividing the line into chunks of size four each:

Example:
Given `0 5 5 18 0 3 1 1 0 5 2 1 0 3 3 0 1 1 3 1 0 3 5 1` I want to make it as:
`[[0 5 5 18], [0 3 1 1], [0 5 2 1], [0 3 3 0], [1 1 3 1], [0 3 5 1]]`
The length is not known from the beginning, otherwise I could have just declared a 2d array, and write its values using two `for` loops, I am think about using a `while` loop and a `for` loop inside, but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define your code as below:

```
String input = "0 5 5 18 0 3 1 1 0 5 2 1 0 3 3 0 1 1 3 1 0 3 5 1";
String data[] = input.split(" ");
int [][] twoD = new int[4][data.length/4];

int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < twoD.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < twoD[i].length; j++) {
        twoD[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(data[k++]);
    }
}

for (int[] is : twoD) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(is));
}
```

output:

```
[0, 5, 5, 18, 0, 3]
[1, 1, 0, 5, 2, 1]
[0, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1]
[3, 1, 0, 3, 5, 1]
```